# Customize a SharePoint 2010 survey required field user message

Tags: 2010, jquery, sharepoint-server, survey

I've created a survey with rating questions and branch logic and most are required fields.  Any suggestions/ideas on how to use Javascript/JQuery to change the OOTB required field user message "You must specify a value for this required field"  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share some bits of the html source around the field validator?

Answer (score 1):

this will be attached specifically to surveys and you can tweak both types of messages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

        //override: "You must specify a value for this required field."

        //per-field validator
        $('.ms-formbodysurvey .ms-formvalidation > span[role="alert"]').text("Please specify a value for this field.");

        //summary validator
        $('.ms-formbodysurvey span.ms-formvalidation[role="alert"]').text("Please make sure all required fields are properly filled.");

});
</script>
```

Comment: I just added this code to change alert in newForm.aspx "You must specify a value for this required field". Unfortunately, after applied this code Formula column Validation in my form not working. Any solution?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why this would break something, unless of course you don't have jquery and the $ is breaking your scripts. check the console for errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. You should add this to both NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var alertSpan= $('span[role="alert"]');
alertSpan.text('My Custom Alert!');

});
</script>
```